# How to improve nested if-else statements?

Tags: java, algorithm

How could I improve nested if-else statements, eg in the following code example (the numbers are not neccesary the same, just example):

```
boolean a, b;
int result = 0;

if (a && b) {
    result = 3;
} else if (a) {
    result = 1;     
} else if (b) {
    result = 2;
}
```

Could this be written better somehow? Or would you think it's ok just as it is?

Comment: I don't need the result for the fourth possibility, but probably initialisation to 0 would make sense.

Comment: The code must be simple, why do you want to make it shorten?  After it will be hard to debug or understand (like if (a) result |= 0x1; ..)

Comment: Why do you want it to be short?  Maintainability is EVERYTHING in software development!  You could of course, write `result = a ? b ? 3 : 1 : b ? 2 : 0;` but who would ever follow it?

Comment: Probably shorten was the wrong word. Improve would fit better here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put this into a method you can return directly which makes it more readable, it also removes this logic to a separate location:

```
public int getThing(final boolean a, final boolean b) {
    if (a && b) {
        return 3;
    }
    if (a) {
        return 1;     
    }
    if (b) {
        return 2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think that using binary operators or the ternary operator really buys you much except future pain trying to work out what you did and why you did it in, say, a year's time.

Comment: I like that point of view!

Answer (score 12):

For the particular numbers given:

```
int result = (a ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 2 : 0);
```

In the more general case, there's really not much wrong with the code you've already written.  It's pretty concise, perfectly legible and easy to comprehend.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (a) result |= 0x1;
if (b) result |= 0x2;
```

Comment: Hm it was just meant as an example as I wrote. The numbers could also be any different.

Comment: Please do mention this explicitly in your question.

Comment: Why use `|=` when `+=` would have the same effect here, but is easier to understand?  And why bother writing `0x` in front of all those numbers?  OP wants it short!

Comment: @DavidWallace the answer appears to assume (incorrectly as it happens, since the OP changed the question) that the value represents a bit mask, in which case using `|` and `0x` would be completely acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't check a and b multiple times.

```
if (a) {
    result = b ? 3 : 1;
} else if (b) {
    result = 2;
}
```

Or, since you asked for short, here is one line, though I prefer the one above.

```
result = a ? (b ? 3 : 1) : b ? 2 : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = (a && b) ? 3 : (a) ? 1 : (b) ? 2 : -1;
```

That -1 is tricky, but i think you cannto say `int result;` because native types cannot be `null`;

Answer (score 0):

one more answer

```
result = a ? result+1 : result ;
result = b ? result+2 : result ;
```

Answer (score 0):

if want `result = x` for `a && !b`, `result = y` for `!a && b`, and `result = z` for `a && b`, then:

`result = (a ? x : 0) + (b ? y : 0) + (a && b ? z - x - y : 0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following matrix:

```
short[][] res = {{-1,1},{2,3}};
```

Here first index stands for `a` values (`0` is for `false`, `1` is for `true`), second is for `b` values. After that you can obtain results in the following manner:

```
int result = res[a == true ? 1 : 0][b == true ? 1 : 0];
```

In this particular case conversion of `if-else` statements into the matrix may seem redundant, but in the case with huge amount of different variations of `a` and `b` (when `a` and `b` are integers, or characters; whatever has the bigger range of possible values than the `boolean`)it can significantly improve readability of your code.